# why come ing with verb after preposition

Tags: verbs, gerunds

why we use "ing" with verb that comes after preposition?

For example: he is accused for breaking a new vase.

here breaking is being used after for

Comment: [Verb after preposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100589/verb-after-preposition) and [Form of verb after a preposition](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225480/form-of-verb-after-a-preposition).

Answer (score -1):

When a non-finite verb form is the object of a preposition, it is almost always a gerund, i.e., the present participle (or *-ing*) form of a verb used as a noun.  The only reason we can give is that it's idiomatic in English, which is only a way of saying that's the way it is.  Of course, this being English, there's an exception:

> He was accused of **breaking** the new vase.
>   He had no choice except **to defend** himself.

The first sentence is the usual case: the gerund *breaking* appears as the object of the preposition *of*.  The second sentence is the rarer case: the infinitive *to defend* appears as the object of the preposition *except*.

Comment: *Historically*, isn't our present participle derived from the gerund, rather than the other way round?  E.g. "He was a-swimming" [=he was in the act of swimming] becoming just "He was swimming".

Comment: @DavidGarner Sorry, I have no idea.  *Present participle* is the lexical term for a particular verb form: the form following *to* in an infinitive plus the suffix *-ing*.  *Gerund* is the term for the role a present participle takes in a sentence, namely subject, object, or complement -- the roles also taken by noun phrases.  Present participles can also take the role of modifier, in which case they're called *participial adjectives*.

Comment: if we're mainly interested in describing English as it is now, wouldn't it be better to say that the present participle and gerund have the same ending, -ing?  After all, you wouldn't say that the possessive "'s'" ending is also used to form the third-person singular present form of verbs.

Comment: The driveby downvoter (belatedly) strikes again. This discourtesy is a plague upon this site. Is the answer wrong? incomplete? misleading? Nobody knows. I have no way to improve the answer if that's the case. If the opposite holds, and the answer is correct, then the questioner (and others) may be left with the wrong impression.

Comment: You might want to clarify that although _to_ can be a preposition in many phrases, that in the phrase _except to defend himself_, _except_ is a preposition (which I initially missed you pointing out) and that _to_ is a particle because it's part of an infinitive.